# How do you replace an entire row that you have the index for with -1?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of indeterminate size with unknown column and row names, as well as a list of row indices and I need to replace every element in those rows with -1.

```
index = c(3,4,5)
ones = as.list(c(rep(as.integer(-1), length(df))))
for (i in index){
  df[i,] <- ones
}
```

However, it's returning this:

```
Error in [<-:
! Assigned data ones must be compatible with
  existing data.
ℹ Error occurred for column ...4.
Caused by error in vec_assign():
! Can't convert <integer> to <character>.
```

Comment: If I define `df <- head(mtcars)` then `df[index, ] <- list(1)` works fine with no loops. If that doesn't work for you please share a small example data frame.

Comment: If you're working with a `tibble`, try converting it to a `data.frame` for this to work. Tibbles are a little stricter.

Comment: @GregorThomas works with tibbles as well. Do you have an example where it would not work?

Comment: @M-- It works with tibbles as long as everything same class. (`mtcars` is all numeric). If you set `ir = iris |> head() |> as_tibble()` then `ir[2:3, ] <- list(1)` will produce an error similar to OP's.